# Jenkins getDescriptor() returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My descriptor populates two lists, i am trying to call the descriptor with the following:

`ZAPDriverDescriptorImpl zapDriver = getDescriptor();`

then i call

`zapDriver.getAllFormats()` and `zapDriver.getAllExportFormats())` to obtain the two lists. I concatenate them into list with only the unique elements.

Full class can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/JordanGS/zaproxy-plugin/blob/development/src/main/java/com/github/jenkinsci/zaproxyplugin/ZAPDriver.java#L815)

The problem is that this works when i'm running jenkins locally (only on the master) but when i do a `master-slave`, this code would execute on the slave and run into a `NullPointerException`

```
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.AbstractDescribableImpl.getDescriptor(AbstractDescribableImpl.java:41)
    at com.github.jenkinsci.zaproxyplugin.ZAPDriver.getDescriptor(ZAPDriver.java:2435)
    at com.github.jenkinsci.zaproxyplugin.ZAPDriver.deleteReports(ZAPDriver.java:815)
    at com.github.jenkinsci.zaproxyplugin.ZAPDriver.executeZAP(ZAPDriver.java:1141)
    at com.github.jenkinsci.zaproxyplugin.ZAPBuilder$ZAPDriverCallable.invoke(ZAPBuilder.java:362)
    at com.github.jenkinsci.zaproxyplugin.ZAPBuilder$ZAPDriverCallable.invoke(ZAPBuilder.java:1)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2720)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Jenkins.getInstance()` from a slave executor. It's not available there because slave machines don't run a Jenkins instance.

Comment: Sorry this is my first plugin, `getDescriptor()` calls `Jenkins.getInstance()`, is that what you're saying? Is there any way for the slave to get the list information?